# "Dale pues" in Nicaraguan Spanish

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, nicaragua, definiciones

In Nicaragua, the phrase "dale pues" is very frequently used. What does the phrase mean, and in what contexts can it be used?

Comment: el "pues" es mágico n_n "ya pues", "no pues", "ven pues"..."como pues????"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being from Nicaragua that means that you agree to do something, use something or agree with someone (sometimes after a discussion when someone has convinced you). A common example:

Question:  Quieres ir al cine? (would you like to see a movie)
answer:    dale pues..   (ok)

Nicaraguans tend not to pronounce the (s) so you might only hear: dale pue...
Also another way to say "dale pues" is "va pues" where sometimes you can hear it "va pue"

All of this is also applicable in Panama, in addition to Nicaragua.

Comment: You mean "*Querés* ir al cine"? :)  So is it basically the same as "de acuerdo" then?

Comment: yes...both are correct. I tend to use more  "Querés ir al cine?" to be honest like you said in your post.  You can say "de acuerdo" but I think is more common to say dale pues.. I use "de acuerdo" occasionally especially when I am having a discussion with someone and I agree so I say "de acuerdo pero" but in that case I might use "esta bien pero.."

Comment: I forgot to mention that another way to say "dale pues" and sounds similar is "va pues"

Comment: Is there any difference between when you can use those two?

Comment: both are the same, cannot think of a difference :)

Comment: Nunca he visto la forma "querés".  ¿Cómo se traduce en inglés?

Answer (score 2):

It means *let's do it* and is commonly used before you are going to use or do something.

Answer (score 1):

It's like saying, "Ok then, do it". It's a goading phrase as well. My wife says it to me all the time, especially when she's not happy.