# Help understanding the meaning of dale pué

Tags: guatemala

My friend is from Guatemala and has been trying to help me learn the meaning of it but I can't get this one.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/115/dale-pues-in-nicaraguan-spanish

Comment: Not Nicaragua, Guatemala. He explained it as "esta bien gracias" but I'm not sure how that translates to English. "Everything is good thanks" possibly?

Comment: @JoeyBrandt it translates more like 'OK then...'

Comment: In Guatemala, it could also mean "let's go" or "let's do this".